# Ansible: prompt to enter enable password on cisco ios

Tags: ansible

I need to make the script prompt for enable password after entering in unprivileged mode in cisco ios. So far this is what I have which works but I don't want to put my real "enable" password on anywhere on my computer.

```
---

- name: Basic Show Commands
hosts: cisco
gather_facts: False
connection: local

tasks:
 - name: show run
   ios_command:
     commands:
      - show run
     provider:
       authorize: yes
       auth_pass: my_enable_password
   register: show_run

- debug:
   var: show_run.stdout_lines

- name: copy show run to file

  local_action: copy content={{show_run.stdout[0]}} dest=/mnt/c/Ansible/show_run
```

I run the playbook as follows:

```
ansible-playbook -u my_username -k /mnt/c/Ansible/show_run.yaml
```

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Have you considered using one of the vault options? Ansible has a vault. There are also hashi_vault filters as well as a few other that allow Ansible to securely retrieve secrets at runtime.

Comment: TBH, I am new to Ansible. I have read about it but I would like to keep it simple for now where possible. I'm hoping there's a way to do this.

Comment: Check the documentation [ansible prompt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html). If you have a specific issue implementing this, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This is very old thread, but for the sake of someone new searching for the answer, I did this-

```
ansible-playbook -u my_username --ask-pass --ask-become-pass /mnt/c/Ansible/show_run.yaml
```

Also, in the host file,

```
[host_group:vars]
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_method=enable
ansible_network_os=ios
```

Answer (score 0):

An option "to make the script prompt for enable password" would be to use [vars_prompt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html#prompts). See the example below

```
...
vars_prompt:
  - name: "my_enable_password"
    prompt: "Cisco auth_pass:"
tasks:
...
```